# ERR: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Im getting the above mentioned error:

Controller:

```
@Component
public class NiftyController {

@Autowired
private RestProxyTemplate restTemplate;



@Autowired
private NiftyDAO niftyDAO;

int count=1;




@Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
//@Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * ?")
public void loadNiftyData() throws URISyntaxException {


    System.out.println("Method executed at every 5 seconds. Current time is : "+ new Date() );
    System.out.println("Executed  " +count++ +"  Times");

    URI uri = new URI("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/niftyStockWatch.json");
    ResponseEntity<NiftyDTO> niftyResponse = restTemplate.getRestTemplate().exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, null, NiftyDTO.class);

    NiftyDTO nifties = niftyResponse.getBody();
    System.out.println(nifties.getTrdVolumesum());
    //List<Nifty> saveNifty = niftyDAO.save(nifties);
    //return (Nifty) nifties;
}
}
```

I want to fetch the data from the above link and save in the database

DTO Class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"latestData","data"})
public class NiftyDTO {

private float trdVolumesumMil;

private String time;

private int declines;

private float trdValueSum;

private float trdValueSumMil;

private int unchanged;

private float trdVolumesum;

private int advances;

public float getTrdVolumesumMil() {
    return trdVolumesumMil;
}

public void setTrdVolumesumMil(float trdVolumesumMil) {
    this.trdVolumesumMil = trdVolumesumMil;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public int getDeclines() {
    return declines;
}

public void setDeclines(int declines) {
    this.declines = declines;
}

public float getTrdValueSum() {
    return trdValueSum;
}

public void setTrdValueSum(float trdValueSum) {
    this.trdValueSum = trdValueSum;
}

public float getTrdValueSumMil() {
    return trdValueSumMil;
}

public void setTrdValueSumMil(float trdValueSumMil) {
    this.trdValueSumMil = trdValueSumMil;
}

public int getUnchanged() {
    return unchanged;
}

public void setUnchanged(int unchanged) {
    this.unchanged = unchanged;
}

public float getTrdVolumesum() {
    return trdVolumesum;
}

public void setTrdVolumesum(float trdVolumesum) {
    this.trdVolumesum = trdVolumesum;
}

public int getAdvances() {
    return advances;
}

public void setAdvances(int advances) {
    this.advances = advances;
}
}
```

RestProxyTemplate:

```
@Component
public final class RestProxyTemplate {


RestTemplate restTemplate;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("MY PROXY GOES HERE",8080);
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,address);
    factory.setProxy(proxy);

    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);
}

public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    return restTemplate;
}
}
```

Error Log:

```
Method executed at every 5 seconds. Current time is : Mon Jun 05 10:45:38 IST 2017
Executed  1  Times
2017-06-05 10:45:38.141  INFO 108988 --- [           main] 
s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 (http)
2017-06-05 10:45:38.153  INFO 108988 --- [           main] 
com.MyApplication.portfolio.PMSApplication      : Started PMSApplication in 5.041 seconds (JVM running for 5.573)
2017-06-05 10:45:39.028 ERROR 108988 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.

org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.MyApplication.portfolio.controller.NiftyDTO] and content type [text/plain]
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:835) ~[spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:819) ~[spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:599) ~[spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:572) ~[spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:493) ~[spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at com.MyApplication.portfolio.controller.NiftyController.loadNiftyData(NiftyController.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) ~[spring-context-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92]
```

Im getting the No Sutiable HttpMessageConverter Found for the response type, can some one suggest the possible solution for this??

Comment: What does the response looks like? What the content type of the response ? You can check the `RestTemplate` for sure about supported content type or encoding type or reponse content can be handled correctly. Post more detail information would do help.

Comment: Im not getting any response.

Comment: So how do you want spring to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to process application/json rather than text/plain.

```
private static void temp() {
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
//        requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application","json")));
        requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("text","plain")));
        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);

// Create a new RestTemplate instance
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

// Add the Jackson message converter
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mc = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() ;
        mc.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("text","plain")));
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(mc);

        String url = "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/niftyStockWatch.json";
        ResponseEntity<NiftyDTO> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, NiftyDTO.class);
        NiftyDTO res = responseEntity.getBody();
        System.out.println(res);
    }
```

Code got from [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-android/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html) and modified a bit

UPDATE: After the change code works fine but there is another error Caused by: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not deserialize value of type float from String "4,092.10": not a valid Float value`

You will need to fix deserializing of data with `,` delimiter.

Comment: wat is this used for?? `HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);` ?

Comment: To indicate which content types we accept - in our case we should accept text/plain which returned from the URL

Comment: `HttpEntity<"wat to write here"> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<> (requestHeaders);`

Comment: `?` char:) I wrote exact code. No need to replace anything.